# Print traceback "ending" on the assert-line, in Python3 unittest addFailure

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-unittest, traceback

I have made a simple, custom `TestResult` class (not inheriting from anything). When my python unittest fails, `addFailure(self, test, err)` is called as expected.

`err[2]` contains a `traceback`

I now print the `traceback` with this command: `traceback.print_tb(err[2])`

The print out contains two more levels than expected/desired.

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 580, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/xplatformer/code/tools/python/exception_test/my_test.py", line 23, in test_my4
    self.assertEqual(5,4)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 800, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 793, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
```

How can I get the `traceback` to "end" at the `assertEqual` (line 23 in `my_test.py`)

Similarly, when extracting the filename like this: `err[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename`, I get `case.py` and not `my_test.py` as expected/desired.
How can I get the filename where the assertion occurred?

Answer (score 0):

from the log it is pretty clear that, there is `self.assertEqual(5,4)` which fails the test case on line `23` in the method `test_my4` in file `/home/xplatformer/code/tools/python/exception_test/my_test.py`

change the `self.assertEqual(5,5)` will pass the test case.

Comment: Hi @XPlatformer If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.